# How to create a UI like JCPenney in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can any body suggest me how to create a UI like [JCPenney](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jcp&hl=en) in android? It seems like carousal, but something different. Is there any library component available which can provide me a UI like this? Please help.

[image: JCPenney app at Google Play]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an accordion. I have found some links that may help you to implement such a behaviour.

[Dynamic accordion creation](https://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/dynamic-accordion-creation-in-android/)

[Accordion view](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view)

[Here is one more](http://android-apps-creater.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-implement-accordian-in-android.html)